# Nullable List<> as out parameter

Tags: c#, list, nullable, out

Is this possible?

```
private void Test(out List<ExampleClass>? ExClass)
{

}
```

A nullable List<> that is also an out parameter?

Comment: Since you had already written the code, why didn't you just try it yourself?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`List<T>` is a reference type (class), so no `?` is required. Just assign `null` to `ExClass` parameter in method body.

Comment: Another way is to have 0 (zero) elements in the list or empty list.

Answer (score 9):

As Anton said, you don't need to use `Nullable<T>` - but it could certainly be an `out` parameter:

```
private void Test(out List<ExampleClass> foo)
```

It's possible you're confusing a nullable `List<T>` with a `List<T?>` which would be valid for value types... for example, you could use:

```
private void Test(out List<Guid?> foo)
```

which would be an out parameter which is a list of nullable guids.

On the other hand, it's not generally nice to have `out` parameters in `void` methods - you should usually use it as the return type instead.

Comment: thanks Jon. the method shown was an example only and thanks for providing an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `?`  just for  nullable ValueTypes.

Answer (score 0):

Being an `out` parameter or not is irrelevant here. But you cannot make a `Nullable<T>` with a class; `T` must be a struct. Otherwise the compiler will complain.

In addition to this, it is considered bad style to capitalise the name of a parameter (use `exClass` instead of `ExClass`). Your programs will work the same, but anybody reading your code might be misled.